# Как удалить элементы от старой связи в typeorm postgres при manytomany?

Tags: postgresql, typeorm

Если сохранять `Post` в помощью `.save()`, то элементы от старой связи  остаются в таблице `Tag`, не удаляются:

```js
// ================ Service ==================== //
const post = new Post();
post.title = createPostDto.title;
post.category = createPostDto.category;
post.content = createPostDto.content;

const tags = createPostDto.tags.split(',').map((tag) => {
  const tagEntity = new Tag();
  tagEntity.tag = tag.trim();
  return tagEntity;
});

post.tags = tags;

const postRes = await this.postRepository.save(post);

// ============= Post Entity ================= //
@Entity()
export class Post {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  title: string;

  @Column()
  category: string;

  @Column()
  content: string;

  @Column({ default: '' })
  imageUrl: string;

  @ManyToOne(() => User, (user) => user.posts)
  user: Relation<User>;

  @ManyToMany(() => Tag, (tag) => tag.posts, {
    cascade: true,
  })
  @JoinTable()
  tags: Relation<Tag[]>;

  @Column({ default: false })
  isFeatured: boolean;

  // **
  @CreateDateColumn()
  createdAt: string;

  @UpdateDateColumn()
  updatedAt: string;
}

// ======================= Tag Entity ==================== //
@Entity()
export class Tag {
  @PrimaryGeneratedColumn()
  id: number;

  @Column()
  tag: string;

  @ManyToMany(() => Post, (post) => post.tags, {
    orphanedRowAction: 'delete',
  })
  posts: Relation<Post[]>;
}
```

Пробовал через `querybuilder`, тоже самое, `onDelete` ничего не меняет.
Они не должны удаляться? Связи нет, почему они остаются? Как удалить в `Typeorm` при `ManyToMany` элементы от старой связи в таблице, когда формируется новая связь при обновлении?

Comment: вы подразумеваете, что удаляется связь между постом и устаревшим-тегом, но устаревгий-тег остаётся в БД? или запись про связь не удаляется?

Comment: @nörbörnën, первое, устаревший тег не удаляется.

Comment: емнип, такое поведение называется OneToMany, а не ManyToMany. ManyToMany подразумевает, что на один и тот же тег будут ссылаться несколько постов, а это не подразумевает удаления тегов при удалении связи.

Comment: @nörbörnën, ясно, спасибо

Comment: собсно, если вам нужно такое эксклюзивное владение тегами тогда и таблица тегов не нужна, можно их прихранить в посте, в поле jsonb